# Inserting multiple rows into the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, insert

Hi I'm dealing with a problem with inserting multiple rows into the database. It should be a list of books, which have a checkbox, so you can add them into your list. I'm getting some values from other tables, and they should be inserted into a my_list table. I think I have a problem with inserting, because the values are right. But when I press the button nothing happens.

```
$sql = "SELECT b.id, b.name, b.author, l.id FROM books b join history h on(k.id=h.id_book) join list l on(l.id=h.id_list) join class c on(c.id=l.id_class) join students s on(s.id_class=c.id) join my_list m on(m.id=m.id_student)  where c.id=(select id_class from students where id=".$_SESSION['login']." and b.id!=n.id_book)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  

?>
<form action="index.php?content=list_books" method="post">
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   ?><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"/><?php  echo  $row["name"]. "/" . $row["author"]. "<br>";
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="add_book">
<?php
} else {
echo "0 books";
}

?>

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add_book'])) {
 foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO my_list (id_book,id_student,id_list) VALUES (".$check.",".$_SESSION['login'].",".$row['l.id'].")";
  $qwe = mysqli_query($insert, $conn); 
   if(!$qwe) {
  echo mysql_error();
  }       
  }
  }
```

Comment: Unrelated really but I suggest using PDO over Mysqli or Mysql. It is a bit more secure and really helps clear up code.
Check out http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php for more

Comment: Where are you getting $row['s.id'] from?

Comment: Oh , that's supposed to be l.id, I was translating it into english and I forgot about that, I will edit it.

Comment: $row['l.id'] is not available to you in the latter part of the code where you are inserting the values.

Comment: When I was trying before it worked, ir echoed all the values and correctly, but now it's not working strange.